# How do I limit how far back a user can view items in a list?

Tags: firebase

I'd like to **limit how far back a user can view** items in a list.
How can I limit a user's access by:
1. **Time** (eg, can access new chat messages from the last 36 hrs)
2. **Volume** (eg, can access only the most recent 100 new chat messages)

I read firebase docs but couldn't find the answer.
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: You can use Firebase's limit, startAt and endAt queries to do this. Details are in the docs here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: @Sara - btw, sorry for the delayed reply. I thought Stackoverflow was set to email me when someone replied, but it didin't.

Comment: @user2957173 no worries. Also, we're testing out some new beta queries features if you're interested. Details are here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/sRcIjFpq45M